# Cannot read property from props in react component

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-redux, axios, react-props

In `ChatRoom` Component, I am trying to load chat between 2 users to render the names of users of the chat. To get the chat, I am firing off `getCurrentChat` function.

`ChatRoom` Component

```
// importing everything
import { getCurrentChat } from '../../actions/chatActions';

class ChatRoom extends Component {
   componentDidMount() {
      // loading chat between 2 people
      this.props.getCurrentChat(this.props.match.params.chatId); 
   };

   render() {
      const { loadingCurrentChat } = this.props.chat;
      console.log(this.props.chat.currentChat);

      return (
         <div className="container">
            {loadingCurrentChat ? <Spinner /> : (
               <div className="row">
                  <h3>ChatId: {this.props.chat.currentChat._id}</h3>

                  <h2>Chat between {this.props.chat.currentChat.user1.name} и {this.props.chat.currentChat.user2.name}</h2>
               </div>
            )}
         </div>
       )
   }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
   auth: state.auth,
   chat: state.chat
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getCurrentChat })(withRouter(ChatRoom));
```

chatActions.js

```
export const getCurrentChat = (chatId) => (dispatch) => {
  dispatch(setLoadingCurrentChat());
  axios.get(`/chat/${chatId}`)
    .then(res =>
      dispatch({
        type: GET_CURRENT_CHAT,
        payload: res.data
      })
    )
    .catch(err =>
      dispatch({
        type: GET_ERRORS,
        payload: err
      })
    );
};
```

chatReducer.js

```
// importing everything
const initialState = {
  currentChat: {},
  loadingCurrentChat: false,
};

export default function (state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_LOADING_CURRENT_CHAT:
      return {
        ...state,
        loadingCurrentChat: true
      }
    case GET_CURRENT_CHAT:
      return {
        ...state,
        currentChat: action.payload,
        loadingCurrentChat: false
      }
  }
}
```

server file where I handle requests from `chatActions.js` - 
`chatController.js`

```
// requiring everything

exports.getCurrentChat = (req, res) => {
  const chatId = req.params.chatId;
  Chat.findById(chatId)
    .populate('user1')
    .populate('user2')
    .exec()
    .then(chat => res.json(chat))
    .catch(err => res.status(400).json(err));
  };
```

When I try `console.log` the `currentChat` in `ChatRoom`, it correctly shows the chat.

`currentChat:`

```
     messages: []
     user1: {
        _id: "5d1328a91e0e5320706cdabb", 
        name: "sarvar", 
     }
     user2: {
        _id: "5d131405ce36ce0ebcf76ae1", 
        name: "jalol makhmudov"
      }
     __v: 0
     _id: "5d329aea3f34fe0b8c6cf336"
```

If I render `currentChat._id` (see `<h3>` element in `ChatRoom`) it correctly displays it.

But if I render `currentChat.user1.name` and `currentChat.user2.name` (see `<h2>` element in `ChatRoom`) it gives an error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
```

Comment: what result you will get if you print  -- this.props.chat.currentChat.user1

Comment: if I ```console.log(this.props.chat.currentChat.user1)``` I get the user1 object: ```name: "sarvar" ```   ```_id: "5d1328a91e0e5320706cdabb"```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Solution

Initialize state with a more accurate shape.

```
const initialState = {
  currentChat: {
    user1: {}
  },
  loadingCurrentChat: false,
};
```

If you cannot do that, put a check like `currentChat.user1 && currentChat.user1.name` before accessing it in JSX.

#### Explanation

`getCurrentChat` is a request which means it will take time to fetch the data. React does not wait for the request to be completed for rendering. One of the reasons why we define `initialState` is because while the request is being completed, React uses `initialState` to render.

In your case, initialState is defined as,

```
const initialState = {
  currentChat: {},
  loadingCurrentChat: false,
};
```

In JavaScript, when you define an empty object `currentChat: {}`, you can access its immediate child without any error. Therefore `currentChat._id` is accessible but since `currentChat.user1` is `undefined`, `currentChat.user1.name` will throw an error.